# User Input date giving error when parsed to SimpeDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to input the date from the user. But the code is giving error at the parse method. The code I am trying is below.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class date_parse {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=input.nextLine();
        SimpleDateFormat f= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        System.out.println(f.parse(s));
    }   
}
```

NOTE -: The code is running well if I directly provide string format date like "01-01-2000" in place os s in parse method

Comment: I don't get any errors running your code

Comment: provide sample of inputs which are not working.

Comment: you need to catch the exception thrown by f.parse(s)

Comment: What error? Post the stacktrace, and show an input that results in an error.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use  `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ParseException; must be caught (Try/Catch) (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112676/parseexception-must-be-caught-try-catch-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't name your class like that in Java. Please go through [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) article to know more about naming conventions in Java. Secondly as Risalat Zaman mentioned the `parse` method throws `ParseException` which need to be handled in your code. Try changing your code as follows:

```
public class DateParse {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=input.nextLine();
        SimpleDateFormat f= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try {
            System.out.println(f.parse(s));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat f= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        System.out.println(f.parse(s));     
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("There is an exception");
    }
```

Comment: It’s not a god answer IMHO. First helping people use `SImpleDateFormat`, a class that we should no longer use, is doing a mis-favour. Second, the code works (I think), but the answer does not explain why. Third catching `Exception` is bad style and also not helpful in explaining why it’s being done.

Comment: Could you enlighten me as to why we should not use SimpleDateFormat please

Comment: Thanks for asking. Oracle says: [Why do we need a new date and time library?](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) Others say: [Still using java.util.Date? Don’t!](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/) and [What's wrong with Java Date & Time API? \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)